# Grouped bar chart by column value using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am trying to display a grouped bar chart for categories encoded as a column value (`col2` in my example)

The legend of the bar chart must display the value encoded in `col2` so `True` and `False` and the bar should be grouped according to these values.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'col1': ['A', 'B', 'A', 'C', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B'],
    'col2': [True, False, True, True, False, True, False, False, False, False, True],
})
df.groupby('col1')['col2'].count().plot(kind = 'bar', legend=True)
```

[image]

Instead, I would like to see something like :

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need:

```
df.groupby(['col1', 'col2']).agg('size').unstack().plot(kind = 'bar', legend=True)
```

[image]

Comment: To get True/False in the order requested by the OP, you could do `.sort_index(axis=1, ascending=False)` between unstacking and plotting